# Motorola XT610 (Droid Pro) Root

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-pro

I've tried rooting my phone using z4root and after the entire process, I still get access denied with the `su` command in `abd shell`.  I followed the instructions at [droidforums](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/motorola-droid-pro/176761-droid-pro-resources-thread-sbf-root-update-instructions.html).  The [first result](http://theunlockr.com/2013/03/05/how-to-root-the-motorola-droid-pro/) from Google suggests the same tool.  Is there anything else that I may have missed, or is this procedure outdated?

```
System Version: 4.7.3.XT610.Verizon.en.US
Model Number: Droid Pro
Android Version: 2.3.4
Kernel Version: 2.6.32.9-ge13b57a
```